# hasura-v2.xx gives graphql-engine-1 exited with code 1 on `hasura metadata track ...`

Tags: postgresql, docker, graphql, hasura, hasura-cli

I'm trying to get started with Hasura. So here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
  graphql-engine:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileHasura
    # command: /bin/sh -c 'hasura metadata track --all-tables --all-relationships --schema public --endpoint http://graphql-engine:8080 && exec graphql-engine serve'
    command: /bin/sh -c 'exec graphql-engine serve'
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./migrations:/hasura-migrations
    - ./metadata:/hasura-metadata
    - ./track_tables.sh:/track_tables.sh
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_CORS_DOMAIN: "*"
volumes:
  db_data:
```

And inside `DockerfileHasura`, I'm just installing the CLI of Hasura so that I can keep track of all the tables / view:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v2.33.0

RUN curl -L https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/raw/stable/cli/get.sh | bash
```

I can't even run the system with `command: /bin/sh -c 'hasura metadata track --all-tables --all-relationships --schema public --endpoint http://graphql-engine:8080 && exec graphql-engine serve'`, it gives me: `graphql-engine-1 exited with code 1`

Then I came to know that, there in v2.xx they no longer support it. But I want to make this reflection hard-coded. So that I dont' have to open up the web console, and edit stuff. Ref: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1418#issuecomment-894306630

Now I'm getting `"field 'product' not found in type: 'query_root'",`. Althouh they have been created.

It's not showing any view / table in the data section:

[image: hasura: No tables or views in this schema]

**So any suggestion or workaround for me? I want to track every table created in my hasura system by default**

Answer (score 0):

If using the graphical console is not appropriate for your use case I would suggest you make a simple script that:

1. extracts the names of tables you want to track from your database (something along the lines of e.g. `select ns.nspname as schema, cl.relname as table_name from pg_class cl join pg_namespace ns on cl.relnamespace = ns.oid where cl.relkind = 'r'`)
2. Uses those names to build a [pg_track_tables](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/api-reference/metadata-api/table-view/#metadata-pg-track-tables) api request that you send to the hasura instance via e.g. `curl`.